# Weakly Nonlinear Analysis of Autonomous Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, reference-request, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

I have been doing linear stability analysis (LSA) of systems of the autonomous form
$$
\frac{du}{dt}=F(u)\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
\frac{dy}{dt}&=f(y,z)\\
\frac{dz}{dt}&=g(y,z)
\end{cases}
$$
where $u=(y,z)$ and $F=(f,g)$, for nonlinear functions $f$ and $g$. I am now interested in doing weakly nonlinear stability analysis (WNSA), as I hope to get a better insight into the solutions of such a system.

However, I have been struggling to find good references for the main methods and tools to perform WNSA on autonomous systems. [This paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1016/j.camwa.2015.08.019), for example, looks at the case of Turing patterns, but the details are somewhat hard to follow. [Turing's original paper](https://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf) on morphogens and reaction-diffusion also contains some explanation (see Section 9.4), but I was wondering if there are more references out there that I could look into, for a general space-independent system such as mine.

Any ideas?

**What I've gathered so far:** While in LSA we look for solutions of the type
$$
u(t)=u^*+\tilde{u}
$$
where $u^*$ is the homogeneous solution and $\tilde{u}$ is a small perturbation which is solution to the linearised problem $\frac{d\tilde{u}}{dt}=\mathbf{J}(u^*)\tilde{u}$, where $\mathbf{J}$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$, given by, in general
$$
\tilde{u}=C^+v^+e^{\lambda^+t}+C^-v^-e^{\lambda^-t}
$$
where $\lambda^\pm$ and $v^\pm$ are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $\mathbf{J}$. $C^+$ and $C^-$ are constants that depend on the initial conditions of the system.

In WNSA, according to these papers [[ref1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001282529090048Z),[ref2](https://jphys.journaldephysique.org/articles/jphys/abs/1984/03/jphys_1984__45_3_505_0/jphys_1984__45_3_505_0.html),[ref3]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00187282.pdf), we aim to look for solutions given by the so-called Stuart-Watson formula given, for reaction-diffusion equations that also depend on the spatial coordinate $x$, by
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{m=0}^3 u_m(x)A^m(t)+O(A^4)
$$
where
$$
u_m(x)=\sum_{j=0}^m u_{mj}\cos(j\omega x)
$$
where $\omega$ is the critical wavenumber, and
$$
\frac{dA}{dt}(t)=\sum_{m=0}^3 b_m A^m(t)+O(A^4)
$$
Finding coefficients $u_{mj}$ and $b_m$ relies then on substituting such candidate solution on the original system, leading to a sequence of vector problems.

In the autonomous system, however, there is no dependence on $x$, so I wonder how I can still apply this method to it. Intuitively I would just drop the cosine terms (or set $\omega=0$) to get
$$
u(t)=\sum_{m=0}^3 u_m A^m(t)+O(A^4)
$$
where $u_m$ are now constants. Is this fine? How do I then select the coefficients $u_m$ and $b_m$?

Notice also that this case mimics the LSA approach when the sums are up to $1$ and $u_0=u^*$, $u_1=1$, $b_0=0$ and $b_1=\lambda^+$, where $\lambda^+$ is the fastest growth rate (eigenvalue with highest real part). $A(t)$ would, in this case, correspond to $\tilde{u}$, I think.